# Non-Parametric Test controlling for third variable

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, sas

There are two laboratories measuring identical samples. One of the lab's data is non-normal, therefore I am looking for a non-parametric test.

After comparing overall differences in the dependent variable (continuous) using Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney, I wish to test for differences between labs based on a third variable.

There are a number of third variables that I wish to test for, and some of them are categorical (2 levels, and 3 levels), and another is ordinal (by month).

Which test would be appropriate? I read about the van Elteren test, but the SAS output did not make sense.

Comment: You said "**One** of the lab's data is non-normal, therefore I am looking for a non-parametric test." -- however, the usual assumptions nonparametric tests tend to make is that the distributions are the ***same*** (apart from location shift). If the shapes are all over the shop, nonparametric tests might be affected as much as ANOVA. Even the common bootstrapping-of-residuals (or a number of other resampling approaches) will be screwed up, because they rely on the ability to swap observations across groups. Resampling within groups might be used (one that resamples the rows of $[X|y]$ say).

Answer (score 2):

The van Elteren test, a stratified Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test, is correct. It is available in PROC freq. There's an example on the SAS website support [documents](http://support.sas.com/kb/25/022.html).

Comment: Could you add a link to the support docs?

Comment: I'm confused as to interpreting my output. The PROC freq gives me a table showing lab on the row, and my dependent variable values in the column. However, the cells are mostly zeros.

Comment: This is the link that I referred to
http://support.sas.com/kb/25/022.html